# Dartzip License Registration on c#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, licenses.licx

we are maintaining a 20 old software programmed in vb6.  There we use some licensed third party tools like DartZip version 1.5.
Since 2 years we are migrating all the modules to c# .net. 
With DartZip I can’t get the license to work. On the same system I compile the vb6 application. On the client side there is no notice of any DartZip trial.
If I compile on the same system the c# / visual studio migration part I got a trial notice on the client.
I tried also to create a licenses.licx file in VS project

```
DartZip.Zip, interop.DartZip
```

Then I got a compilation error.

```
Error   1   Exception occurred creating type 'DartZip.Zip,   Interop.DartZip, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' System.MissingMethodException: Constructor on type 'DartZip.Zip' not found.    F:\Proman-dev\PromanX_KundenBrunch\PromanXLicence\licenses.licx 1   PromanXLicence
```

here a part of the used code

```
using DartZip;
public static void ReadLicence(string aPath, out Status_ReadLicence aStatus)
{
  if (System.IO.File.Exists(Path.Combine(aPath, gLicenceFileName)))
 {
 try
 {
      string lCustomInfo = String.Empty;
      System.IO.File.Copy(Path.Combine(aPath, gLicenceFileName), Path.Combine(lTempPath, gLicenceFileName), true);
      DartZip.Zip z = new Zip();
      z.FileStore.Load(Path.Combine(lTempPath, gLicenceFileName));
      .....
```

since we are migrating all to a new system, we won't need DartZip any more. But during the migration it would make everything easier.

Has anyone any idea how I could use during the migration the old darzip license on visual studio / c#?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try creating an empty `Licenses.licx` file inside your project, on `Properties\licenses.licx`.

Most 3rd-party libraries are satisfied with that when compiling the project.

Then also install the [EmptyLicensesLicx](https://github.com/caioproiete/EmptyLicensesLicx) nuget package, and it will make sure there's always an empty `Licenses.licx` in that same location.